# How to get all CheckBoxFor's name on Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

This is how my checkboxes look like since i am using `Html helpers` which is inside my View:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The isSelected field is required." id="idstoselect" name="[2].isSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="[2].isSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

I am trying to implement a `Check all` checkbox but i am having trouble selecting all of them due to their name format..

I have my jquery inside my `Layout View` and it's like this as of now:

```
$('#selectall').click(function () {

     //how to select all of them?
});
```

Normally,  i can do something like

```
$("input[name='onenameforall']").attr("checked",this.checked))
```

If i won't use `HtmlHelpers` since i will need to setup the names manually to `onenameforall`. Do i need to reimplement? My checkboxes go in an array of `[2].isSelected`. I am thinking of getting the size of the model then make a for loop from it but my functions are located inside my layout view.

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));` (or give them a class name)

Comment: Oh alright that worked. I just need to provide one class name for all of them? if so then how do i select them? just replace type with class?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/tsjuhzfn/

Comment: If you give them a class name (say `... new { @class = "checkbox" }`) then its just `$('.checkbox').prop(..)`

Comment: Oh alright thank you so much.

Comment: @sushil oh thank you

Comment: you're most welcome @CarlosMiguelColanta :)

Comment: @Sushil, I don't think that was directed to you :) - OP is generating collections in a loop so the controls are `name="[0].isSelected"`, `name="[1].isSelected"`, `name="[2].isSelected"` etc. (they are not all the same)

Comment: oh @StephenMuecke. i saw the html and it had the same names so I wrote it that way. thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all checkboxes using

```
$('#selectall').click(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

alternatively, give the checkboxes your generating in the loop a class name

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].isSelected, new { @class = "mycheckbox" })
```

and in the script

```
$('#selectall').click(function () {
    $('.mycheckbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```